# <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, lambda

I use an image to a button in Tkinter. I want to pass the arguments with canvas.tag_bind.
here is my code:

```
canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<Button-1>', lambda x,y: self.validateLogin(username,password))

def validateLogin(self,username,password):

#...
```

When I click on that button there is an error: "TypeError: App.login..() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" . How can I pass two arguments?

Comment: Where do `username` and `password` come from?  We could use some more context.

Comment: The function passed to `tag_bind` must take exactly 1 argument, the `event`.  You can't make it do anything else. It's not at all clear what you think the second argument is supposed to even be.

Comment: Can you pass the full traceback? We shouldn't have to guess what 'App.login..." is. The handler you register with tag_bind takes a single `event` parameter, not the two parameters `x,y` given in your `lambda`.

Comment: next problems: This code assumes that `username` and `password` are in the global namespace. If not, that's your next error. After that, you'll have the problem that `self` isn't defined in the `lambda` function. Perhaps, instead of a lambda, you should be calling a method on the same object as `validateLogin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is that Tk is not going to pass two arguments to your lambda.  It's only going to pass one, which you don't care about.  You need:

```
canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<Button-1>', lambda e: self.validateLogin(username,password))
```

However, there's a problem here.  Where do `username` and `password` come from?  It gets confusing when you think about what is executed when.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking of `command=`, where there are no parameters passed.